# Install AWS CLI on heroku

Tags: heroku, aws-cli

I would like to use the [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/de/cli/) in an Heroku Ruby project (mainly to use it with a thin wrapper from the ruby application).

Is there any standard way to install additional software like this into an existing application with a Gemfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1) use [buildpack-multi](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to install buildpacks both for ruby and python:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
echo "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby" >> .buildpacks    
echo "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python" >> .buildpacks
echo "web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT" > Procfile
```

2) add a `requirements.txt` file to the root of the project, containing the desired pip package:

```
echo "awscli" >> requirements.txt
```

3) deploy to Heroku

```
git add .buildpacks requirements.txt Procfile
git commit -a -m "use buildpacks for ruby and python, install aws cli"
git push heroku
```

This works just fine and allows me to use my aws scripts from my ruby app.
As was pointed out to me, using [fog](http://fog.io/) is probably the better solution in the long term.

Comment: Im my case I had to rename the `requisites.txt` to `requirements.txt` for the app to deploy correctly on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker to vendor things for Heroku apps.

Add a Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

COPY . /app
```

Then build an image and run a container:

```
$ docker build .
$ docker run -it $image_id bash

# apt-get update && apt-get install jq
```

Now you can copy the data out from another terminal:

```
$ docker cp $container_id:/usr/bin/jq .
```

The `aws-cli` tool is tricker because it needs a whole Python environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Heroku buildpack for the AWS CLI via running:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku-community/awscli
```

More details can be found [on herokus page](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-awscli), or in  [the buildpack's git repo](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-awscli).